# The pronunciation of "peripheral"

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, suffixes, ipa, derivational-morphology

Some time ago, I heard the pronunciation of the word *peripheral* on a TV show (Brain Games, to be exact). Very surprised to hear /pəɹɪfəɹəl/, I asked two close relatives whether that was how the word should really be said, in their opinion. They asked, "How else would you say it?"

Apparently, my pronunciation of /pəɹ.ɪ.fɹiəl/ doesn't exist in any dictionary and the closest I could find was one on Wiktionary, /pəɹɪfiəl/ with no ar. It makes sense etymologically: the word is a form of *periphery* with the suffix *-al* added.

**My questions:** is this pronunciation widespread? Is it a form some consider archaic, such as *rooves* (which I also use)? Do you think it's just a solecism that came about by analogy with *periphery*?

Comment: I don't read IPA (and can't find a functioning pronouncer anywhere), but [Merriam-Webster](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peripheral) provides an IPA of `\pə-ˈri-f(ə-)rəl\ ` and pronounces it pretty much as I would, only a hair stilted.

Comment: (I gather the main difference you're focusing on is "fer" vs "fre".  I don't recall ever hearing the word credibly pronounced with "fre".)

Comment: I don't read IPA too good either (we're the blind leading the blind here! :) But the guy doing the talking on that MW page does seem to be somewhat "over-enunciating", and I note that the IPA rendition is **\pə-ˈri-f(ə-)rəl\** (i.e. - the schwa between /f/ and /r/ is effectively "optional"). In practice, I wouldn't normally enunciate it myself, so ***peripheral*** usually has only *three* syllables for me. On the other hand, I'd nearly always enunciate the corresponding element in ***periphery***, so that one invariably has *four* syllables. As you can see, consistency is not my strong suit!

Comment: What exactly are you asking? "Is this pronunciation widespread?" _Which_ this? yours or MW or Brain Games or what? Which one are you possibly calling the solecism?

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/peripheral_1?q=peripheral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think most people would consider the pronunciation /pəˈrɪfriəl/ "puh-RIF-ri-al" for *peripheral* nonstandard, for several reasons. Like you, I was unable to find any dictionary that lists it, or any other evidence that it is used by people other than you. It also doesn't match up with the spelling.

The ending *-eral* is normally pronounced as /ərəl/ or /rəl/). There is generally no stress on the vowel "e" here, and it is often dropped entirely in the pronunciation (examples: *general*, *several*, *ephemeral*, pronounced with /ərəl/ or /rəl/). It generally cannot be pronounced as /əriəl/ or /riəl/.

While a lack of agreement with the spelling doesn't always cause a pronunciation to be considered incorrect (there are words like *marriage* and *carriage* where an "i" is written but generally *not* pronounced), in many cases it does (as in "mischiev**i**ous" for [*mischievous*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mischievous), or "griev**i**ous" for [*grievous*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grievous)). I don't remember hearing this pronunciation before, but it seems wrong to me because of this sound-spelling mismatch.

If we do vary the spelling, I found that Oxford Dictionaries does list a variant /ˌpɛrᵻˈfɪərɪəl/ (that's perry-FEAR-ial, so not quite the same pronunciation) that is spelled [*peripherial*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peripherial). They note it to be rare; the spelling definitely is (see this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peripherial%2Cperipheral&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperipherial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperipheral%3B%2Cc0), courtesy of Fumblefingers' comment). But apparently, this form actually is older than the form *peripheral*. So your pronunciation doesn't seem to be archaic, but your inclusion of the *-y/-i-* before the ending *-al* is. The adjective *peripheral* is definitely formed in an unusual way; I haven't been able to find any other adjective ending in *-eral* that corresponds to a noun ending in *-ery*. But despite this, it has become the standard form used today.

If we look at the pronunciation of some currently-used words that end in *-erial*, we can see that they generally display the same stress shift: the  adjectives corresponding to *artery*, *ministry*, *matter* and *manager* are *arterial*, *ministerial*, *material* and *managerial*, all pronounced with /ˈɪəriəl/.

And expanding to look at other words ending in the sound /riəl/, a vowel letter before it always seems to be stressed, never dropped (see *janitorial, adversarial, tenurial*). There is a word /ˈfɪmbriəl/ where /riəl/ comes after a consonant (so it has the same phonetic structure as your pronunciation /pə⁠ˈrɪfriəl/), but it is spelled *fimbrial*, not **fimberal* (or even **fimberial*), and the corresponding noun is *fimbria* /ˈfɪmbriə/ not **fimbery* /ˈfɪmbəri/.

So even if you spell the word *peripherial*,  /pəˈrɪfriəl/ would *still* be an odd pronunciation. Of course, it's up to you whether you want to change your pronunciation to the more usual one, or stick with your accustomed [*mumpsimus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mumpsimus).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! With this, I wouldn't say the spelling differs too much from the pronunciation (it appears like a dropped schwa), but the original pronunciation and mine do differ. You've given me hope and a new spelling I will use.

Comment: I can't go with this. Bearing in mind that [a **solecism** is a phrase that trespasses the rules of grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solecism), it doesn't really seem at all appropriate. But even if we stretch the meaning a bit (so it can include "mispronunciations"), it doesn't work for me. Partly because per M-W's phonetic transcription the middle schwa is "optional", but mainly because if we had to make our pronunciation consistent with *spelling*, practically everything Anglophones currently say would be "wrong".

Comment: @FumbleFingers — That might be the original definition but a solecism can also be defined as "a nonstandard or ungrammatical usage." See [here](http://dictionary.com/browse/solecism).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: thanks for the link; I modified my wording to "non-standard." The middle schwa being optional didn't seem to me to be the main point of the OP's question; I thought it was mainly about the inclusion of an /i/ directly before the /əl/. There's a difference between /pəˈɹɪfɹəl/, which does seem to be recorded in dictionaries, and /pəˈɹɪfɹiəl/, which doesn't.

Comment: sumelic - My mistake, sorry. I didn't even *see* that extraneous /i/ in OP's transcription. Misconceived downvote removed. Yeah - I think we can reasonably say that OP is in a *very* small minority here (feasibly a minority of one, since I'm sure I've never heard anyone say the word the way [that virtually non-existing spelling variant](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peripherial%2Cperipheral&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperipherial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperipheral%3B%2Cc0) might suggest. It's certainly not on a par with ***nucular***

Comment: ...by the way, my ***literary*** almost always has only three syllables (correspondingly, my ***literal*** usually only has at most 2.1 syllables).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I haven't published any books, so that means there's at least one other person with a different pronunciation of *peripheral*. We're a minority of two that must be recognized! :-D

Comment: @WhiteHatHacker I'm rereading all that you've written and I don't see this 'at least one other person'. Who is it again?

Comment: @Mitch: the person(s) who uses *peripherial* is recorded by Google Books in FumbleFinger's link.

Comment: @Sumelic: Your right: /pəˈɹɪfriəl/would still be on odd pronunciation. I think I'll stick with /ˌperɪˈfiriəl/ from now on to keep the pattern used in the related words you brought up. Thanks again!

Comment: @WhiteHatHacker You need to do more thorough research before making inferences. _All_ those instances through Google Books (or through regular Google search) are 1) written and 2) accompanied in a following or previous sentence where it is spelled 'peripheral'. I take that unconscionable variance to be a typo.

Comment: @Mitch: The first selection of written publications I clicked on from the Google Books link contained no mention of the spelling *peripheral*, and I did not say anything of a regular Google search (it does not give historical examples).

Comment: @WhiteHatHacker can you give a link to that site you are talking about? (Or another one where there is only 'peripherial')

Comment: @Mitch: Sure, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q="peripherial"&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1920&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) you are.

Comment: @WhiteHatHacker Nice. There are a number of sources there with many uses of the 'p' word which are consistently spelled 'peripherial'. Checking OED now.

Comment: OED has a separate entry for ***peripherial***, which it says is "rare" - though apparently still "current", in that their last citation is 1973. But I hadn't been aware of it before this Q, and my guess is *most* native speakers won't recognise it. So they'll think you're making a mistake if you use it (unless you hit them over the head with a copy of OED!).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes! I will be well-prepared to give them the complete backstory.

Comment: @WhiteHatHacker: Since I've looked it up in OED and (sorta) "vindicated" your usage, I hope you won't feel the need to hit *me* over the head with [21,728 pages in 20 volumes of OED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary). But to be on the safe side, I'm gonna wear my [Odinson](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270788/) tin hat and keep my head down! :)

Answer (score 1):

Most people say BrE /pᵻˈrɪf(ə)rəl/ , /pᵻˈrɪf(ə)rl̩/ , AmE /pəˈrɪf(ə)rəl/

There is an entry in the OED for 'peripherial' as an alternate for peripheral.

It is labeled '*rare*' and is given the pronunciation 
BrE /ˌpɛrᵻˈfɪərɪəl/, AmE /ˌpɛrəˈfɪriəl/

You may well have seen one of the rare occurrences of 'peripherial' and that's where you came up with the pronunciation that doesn't match what the others around you use.

Because it is labeled rare in the OED I'd suggest that you use the more common pronunciation. In the links you gave, every time I see 'peripherial', even when repeated, it just looks a typo.

Comment: haha...now that I read sumelic's answer again, I realize he found the same thing, so my answer is superfluous.